# htaccess for main domain using sub directory files

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, dns, subdomain

I want to ask you, if someone may to help me.

I have a domain http://domain.com and one sub-domain http://new.domain.com.

My files structure is regular (nothing special):

- public_html/
- - file.php
- - file1.php
- - index.php
- - new/
- - - file.php
- - - file1.php
- - - index.php

The question is: Do I may to use the files from my public_html/new  directory for my mine domain using some htaccess rules?
Of course the final goal is to not to be changed my mine url with my subdomain url.

Something like: when someone open doman.com to see the files from my sub-directory "new" (which means to see my subdomain site... ) from new.domain.com

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean something like this? (in the htaccess file in your public_html folder):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(?!new/)(.*)$ /new/$1 [L]
```

Comment: @FireBull sorry, left out the "new" part of the target

Comment: Sorry, but your example don't work... I found very helpfull doc for this: http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Transparently_redirect_your_root_directory_to_a_subdirectory